# Refresh page without losing the Post value

Tags: php, html

How do I maintain the $post value when a page is refreshed; In other words how do I refresh the page without losing the Post value

Comment: You can try storing the value in a session variable, or POST the value again when you refresh the page. :o

Comment: Don't mean to seem dumb but how exactly would I store it in the sessions

Comment: @dames your right a lot more work would need to be done to achieve this with a session without first posting back to the server. some sort of call would need to be made i.e Ajax call when the user has entered the details.

Comment: @GlynJackson it's not "so much work", and it can be achieved with form submitting as well as AJAX. See my answer below!

Comment: @dames are you staying the form was first submitted, before wanted to preserve, if so then yes a session would work however, if the user filling in the form does not hit submit for the first time, then 'hard' refreshes the page will not work. no other way around this without sending the data back to the server.

Comment: @GlynJackson you're right, the question is a bit vague: a "refresh" will not be saved by a form - only `submit` will. With Ajax it is possible. Also, it can be implemented by JS & cookies.

Comment: @GlynJackson are you say these answers will not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This in not possible without a page submit in the first place! Unless you somehow submitted the form fields back to the server  i.e. Without Page Refresh using jQuery etc. Somesort of Auto Save Form script.

If this is for validation checks no need for sessions as suggested.

User fills in the form and submits back to self
Sever side validation fails

$_GET

```
    <input type="hidden" name="first" 
   value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($first, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

validation message, end.

alternatively as suggested save the whole post in a session, something like this, but again has to be first submitted to work....

$_POST

```
if(isset($_POST) & count($_POST)) { $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; }
if(isset($_SESSION['post']) && count($_SESSION['post'])) { $_POST = $_SESSION['post']; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. POST variables may not be re-sent, if they are, the browser usually does this when the user refreshes the page.

The POST variable will never be re-set if the user clicks a link to another page instead of refreshing.

If `$post` is a normal variable, then it will never be saved.

If you need to save something, you need to use cookies. `$_SESSION` is an implementation of cookies. Cookies are data that is stored on the user's browser, and are re-sent with every request.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

The $_SESSION variable is just an associative array, so to use it, simply do something like:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = $bar
```

Comment: "POST variables may not be re-sent" - not true! "if the user clicks a link to another page" - it will be `GET` so it only makes sense that the `POST` params will not be saved. And there is a perfect sense in keeping the form filled, for example, if the user tries to register and selects an already existing username, the submit should fail - but you wouldn't want the user to start typing all the info from scratch, and of course there is no UI validation that can check it - only server-side.

Comment: I mean that if the user refreshes the page after a form submit, the browser will ask whether the user wants to resend posted data - thus the POST data can be resent, or it could also NOT be re-sent. ie. web developer cannot control this.

Comment: of course that a web-developer can control this - if the `submit` was successful - it can redirect the customer to another page (or `unset` the `POST` variables) and prevent re-submitting the same data. If the `submit` failed, it can use the same `POST` values and pre-fill the form for the user.

Comment: I believe that is outside the scope of what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could save your $_POST values inside of $_SESSION's
Save your all $_POST's like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['value1'] = $_POST['value1'];
$_SESSION['value2'] = $_POST['value2'];
// ETC...
echo "<input type='text' name='value1' value='".$_SESSION['value1']."' />";
echo "<input type='text' name='value2' value='".$_SESSION['value2']."' />";
?>
```

Comment: Don't mean to seem dumb but how exactly would I store it in the sessions

Comment: so for example with my program I call my session by: `include(session.php)` I would just add what you wrote below `include(session.php)` ?

Comment: After submitting the form, you should set $_POST values inside of $_SESSION .. and  inside of form (where are input's) as value you should set matching session `value='"$_SESSION['blabla']"'`... i hope you got it

Comment: I think I got it I will attempt and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Actually in html forms it keeps post data. 
this is valuble when you need to keep inserted data in the textboxes.

```
  <form> 
<input type="text" name="student_name" value="<?php echo 
isset($_POST['student_name']) ? $_POST['student_name']:'';    
?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same value that you got in the `POST` inside the form, this way, when you submit it - it'll stay there.

An little example:

```
<?php
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var']);
?>
<form id="1" name="1" action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" value="<?php print $var;?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

put post values to session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["POST_VARS"]=$_POST;
```

and you can fetch this value in another page like

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["POST_VARS"]["name"];
$_SESSION["POST_VARS"]["address"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file to save post data so the data will not will not be removed until someone remove the file and of-course you can modify the file easily

```
if($_POST['name'])
{
$file = fopen('poststored.txt','wb'); 
fwrite($file,''.$_POST['value'].'');
fclose($file);
} 

if (file_exists('poststored.txt')) {
$file = fopen('ipSelected.txt', 'r');
$value = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
}
```

so your post value stored in `$value`.

Comment: what happens when you have 2 or more users accessing the page? you store all the data to the file?!