# $_POST'value can only be used for one time?

Tags: php, post

`post-data.php` cantain a form to post user'name into  `show-post-data.php`.
post-data.php

```
<form method="post" action="show-post-data.php">
user:<input type="text" name="user"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Only one command `var_dump($_POST);`in `show-post-data.php`

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

1.click `127.0.0.1/post-data.php` in browser.
2.input `tom` and click submit button.
3.click `127.0.0.1/show-post-data.php` in browser.
We get output as below:

```
array(2) { ["user"]=> string(3) "tom" ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" }
```

4.click `127.0.0.1/show-post-data.php` in browser for second time.

Nothing as output.`$_POST` is empty now.
$_POST'value  can only be used for one time?

Comment: because your form method is post, if you want to get multiple times then use form method is GET (your data show in the url) also you can use seesion

Comment: for more details read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234545/refresh-page-without-losing-the-post-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the HTTP protocol is stateless, which means that the information that you send in a request will be only available for that request (unless you store it in the server).

When you send information in a POST, that arrives to the server (to your PHP code) in the variable `$_POST`, you can use in in that request. In the next page load, that variable will be empty unless you send new information again. That is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` value can only be used for one time?

**NO**, It can be used several time but it should be only available in the page to where it is posted.

If you posted the value to a specific URL, the posted variable can only be accessed in that specified URL for that time. Not in other URL's or for other time.

If you need to used in other sections/pages, you have to save the value or have to store in session or cookie.

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)) { 
  $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; 
}
if(isset($_SESSION['post']) && count($_SESSION['post'])) { 
  $_POST = $_SESSION['post']; 
}
```